# ggplot function not found in jupyter notebook with rpy2

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing, rpy2

I am working on a computer cluster and testing out how to use a Jupyter notebook on it. I encountered this problem while trying to use ggplot2. I've tried installing the package in the notebook, with R in the command line, and with conda install, and r-ggplot2 (version 2.2.1) shows up in conda packages. Any ideas?

[image: The error I got on the notebook is here]

Comment: I couldn't see an error in the uploaded image. Where is the problem?

Comment: just updated the image with the error. It can't find the ggplot function

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour]!

Please put your MWE and the error message in text, do _not_ link a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judged by your screenshot, you are running a python-based notebook. It looks as if you are trying to use `ggplot` as part of the python package `rpy2`.

Based on [this source](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/graphics.html), `ggplot` is present in `rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2`, so you might want to try something like

```python
from rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 import ggplot

...
ggplot(data=df)
```

Comment: I got this error:

~/.conda/envs/general/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py in <module>()

     53 NULL = robjects.NULL

     54 

---> 55 ggplot2 = importr('ggplot2', on_conflict="warn")

     56 ggplot2 = WeakPackage(ggplot2._env,

     57                       ggplot2.__rname__,

Comment: ~/.conda/envs/general/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python, symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Comment: I'm really not an expert in rpy2. In Jupyter notebooks, you can use inspection to find which packages/modules/functions are present. Simplest way: type `import rpy2.` in a cell and hit `TAB`. It should show you all possible submodules. Continue and try to figure out what's going on. Are you sure rpy2 was installed correctly?

Comment: Yes, rpy2 was installed. I messed around and found that I needed to install r-ggplot2 with conda, and it finally worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: Correct.  All you need is to do the conda install r-ggplot2 in your jupyter environment to get this going.  The other thing to do is to restart your notebook's kernel from the menu  Kernel --> Restart and Clear Output so that your session knows of the update.  Just use your %R require(ggplot2) and don't worry about the rpy2 libarary loading unless you are in fact using python to plot, which was not the case in the question example above.